# Definition of ordinal exponentiation

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I found that the usual ordinal exponentiation $\alpha^{\beta}$ is the set of functions from $\beta$ to $\alpha$ with finite support, ordered by antilexicographic order. (least significant position first) It cannot be defined on whole functions, since $f,g:\omega \to 2$ given by $f=(0,1,0,1,\cdots)$ and $g=(1,0,1,0,\cdots)$ are not comparable.

Then how about the lexicographic order? Isn't it possible to define well order on the set of all functions from $\beta$ to $\alpha$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lexiographic order defines a linear order on ${}^\beta\alpha$, but in general, it is not a well-ordering. For example, in the case ${}^\omega2$, the set 
$$
\{ (1,0,\ldots), (0,1,0, \ldots), (0,0,1,0,\ldots), \ldots \}
$$
does not have a lexicographic least element.